# How can echo the .env.list file in docker run command in jenkins

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins

I would like to echo out the `.env.list` values used in the docker run command in Jenkins, I have tried as follows `echo "Print the env.list file: ${.env.list}"`
Could someone please advise how can I print the .env.list file in docker run command

```
          sh """
            docker run --env-file bookpro-co/.env.list ${baseUrlConfig} \
              -v \"${ARTEFACT_DIR}:/artefacts\" \
              -v \"${env.WORKSPACE}/bookpro-co:/bookpro-test\" \
               cypress:latest \
                /node_modules/.bin/cypress-tags ${cypressArgs}
            echo "Print the env.list file: ${.env.list}"
            """
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for `cat` instead of `echo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ tripleee suggested, I believe the problem is the absence of a call to `cat` which will display file contents. I think you would want something like this would work:

```
     sh """
        docker run --env-file bookpro-co/.env.list ${baseUrlConfig} \
          -v \"${ARTEFACT_DIR}:/artefacts\" \
          -v \"${env.WORKSPACE}/bookpro-co:/bookpro-test\" \
           cypress:latest \
            /node_modules/.bin/cypress-tags ${cypressArgs}
        echo "Print the env.list file: $(cat .env.list)"
        """
```